# how to start the linux tomcat on nohup mode on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I used below command in jenkins, After execute this command, It shows that tomcat is started but tomcat is not started

> #!/bin/bash
>
> TOMCAT_HOME=/home/apache-tomcat
>
> nohup $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh &

I need run tomcat in nohup mode on linux machine with Jenkins